# How to map function f to every element

Tags: list-manipulation

```
MapAt[f, {{a, b, {c, d}}, {d, {e, g, {c, d}}}}, 1]
```

How to operate to get such a result:

```
{{f[a], f[b], {f[c], f[d]}}, {f[d], {f[e], f[g], {f[c], f[d]}}}}
```

Comment: Map[f, {{a, b, {c, d}}, {d, {e, g, {c, d}}}}, {-1}]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One can also temporarily apply a `Listable` function with

```
Function[x, f[x], Listable][list]
```

Listability works differently than mapping to level `{-1}` when the elements of the list have parts:

```
Function[x, f[x], Listable][{b, {e, g, {c, a + Exp[d]}}}]
(*  {f[b], {f[e], f[g], {f[c], f[a + E^d]}}}  *)

Map[f, {b, {e, g, {c, a + Exp[d]}}}, {-1}]
(*  {f[b], {f[e], f[g], {f[c], f[a] + f[E]^f[d]}}}  *)
```

Answer (score 7):

you can also give the attribute  `Listable` to your function

```
SetAttributes[f, Listable]
```

and then simply write

```
f@{{a, b, {c, d}}, {d, {e, g, {c, d}}}}
```